# Missing keyword on sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa

My query is written to join 3 table and return specific columns but it is giving error missing Keyword

```
select count(distinct generatedAlias0) from order generatedAlias0 
 inner join 
 generatedAlias0.customer generatedAlias1 
 inner join 
 generatedAlias0.employee generatedAlias2 
 on 
 generatedAlias0.id=generatedAlias0.employee 
 group by 
 generatedAlias0.employee, generatedAlias0.id;
```

Comment: This is JPA error - the query text itself is correct in MySQL (but absolutely illogical).

Comment: Is 'order' an entity or table somewhere? Order is a reserved word in SQL, so cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

There no join condition in the first INNER JOIN.  Needs 'on'

Comment: Yes, join should take the form `INNER JOIN <table> [<alias>] ON <predicate>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner join needs an on Such as: INNER JOIN table1 on table1.name = table2.name